# How to fix flow to look at package.json “module” instead of “main”

Tags: webpack, flowtype, package.json, yarn-workspaces

I'm currently importing a yarn workspace package that has the `main` and `module` field defined in the package.json

```
{
  "name": "@mycompany/utils",
  "version": "0.0.3",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "src/index.js"
}
```

My `create-react-app` setup automatically uses the `module` through webpack but `flow` is complaining that `@mycompany/utils` package is undefined.

> So my question is how do I `flow` to look at the `module` path instead of `main`

**Edit**: I realize I wasn't clear when I first asked the question

- Note: This is important. I want to be able to have updates to the flow types while developing without having to re-build every time I make changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could publish a flow version of your source as `dist/index.js.flow` within this file, you can have `export * from '../src/index.mjs'`;